# Substring in Java Eclipse Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm pretty new to this. I'm working on an app in eclipse to read card reader input. Currently, the card reader as usual reads out the card details all in a single row of entry (its a tract 2 reader). It will be changed to a track1 card reader, then I can use the cardHolderName text. Here's a sample card output

```
;1234567890111213=12345678901113141516?
```

I would like to;

1. remove the first ";" everytime a card is read
2. Add the first 16 digits (after the ";") to a textfield
3. Remove the "="
4. display the first 4 digits after the "=" sign in another textfield

So the two textfields should display:

```
Textfield1:1234567890111213
Textfield2: 12/34
```

I tried using the substring() method in the setText lines, but it didn't provide any results. Can anyone help identify where I'm making a mistake ?

The `.java` code i am  working on is below; Much appreciated!

```
package com.square;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Payments extends Activity {
    private UpdateBytesHandler updateBytesHandler;
    private UpdateBitsHandler updateBitsHandler;
    private TextView decodedStringView;
    private TextView strippedBinaryView;
    private TextView holderName;
    private TextView expiryDate;
    private TextView cardNumber;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;
    private MagRead read;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbtn);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        decodedStringView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bytes);
        strippedBinaryView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bits);
        holderName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.holderNameReal);
        cardNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cardNumberReal);
        expiryDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expiry);

        read = new MagRead();
        read.addListener(new MagReadListener() {

            @Override
            public void updateBytes(String bytes) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = bytes;
                updateBytesHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateBits(String bits) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = bits;
                updateBitsHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }   

        });
        MicListener ml = new MicListener();
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(ml);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(ml);
        updateBytesHandler = new UpdateBytesHandler();
        updateBitsHandler = new UpdateBitsHandler();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        read.release();
    }



    /**
     * Listener called with the mic status button is clicked, and when the zero level or noise thresholds are changed
     */
    private class MicListener implements OnClickListener{

        /**
         * Called when the mic button is clicked
         * @param
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == stopBtn){//stop listening
                stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
                startBtn.setEnabled(true);
                read.stop();
            }else if(v == startBtn) {//start listening
                stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
                startBtn.setEnabled(false);
                read.start();
            }
        }

    }


    private class UpdateBytesHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String bytes = (String)msg.obj;
            decodedStringView.setText(bytes);
        }

    }

    private class UpdateBitsHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String bits = (String)msg.obj;
            strippedBinaryView.setText(bits);
        }

    }

    private class UpdateHolderName extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String holderN = (String)msg.obj;
            holderName.setText(holderN);
        }

    }

    private class UpdateCardNumber extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String cardN = (String)msg.obj;
            cardNumber.setText(cardN);

        }

    }

    private class UpdateExpiry extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String exp = (String)msg.obj;
            expiryDate.setText(exp);

        }

    }



}`
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?  With a debugger?

Comment: "I tried using the substring() methodin the setText lines" no, you didn't. substring is nowhere to be found in the code you posted.

Comment: yes, you never showed the code you said you are using.

Comment: What kind of card reader are you using?

Comment: Yes, I removed the substring() entry. I used it at the; holderName.setText(holderN).substring(1);  I was trying to remove the ";"

Answer (score 0):

Consider this to your string

```
String data = ";1234567890111213=12345678901113141516?"
String first= data.substring(1, 17);
String second= data.substring(18, data.length()-1);
```

For more understanding, follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check the java String method `substring(i,j)`

```
String code = ";1234567890111213=12345678901113141516?";
String first = code.substring(1,17);
String second = code.substring(18,19) + "/" + code.substring(20,21);
```

**IMPORTANT** `substring()` returns a new String !

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

So you must store the result in a variable.

Comment: it didnt work. heres how i tried doing it; private class UpdateCardNumber extends Handler { Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { String code = (String) decodedStringView.getText(); String cardN = code.substring(1,17); } } private class UpdateExpiry extends Handler { Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { String code1 = (String) decodedStringView.getText(); String expiryDate = code1.substring(18,19) + "/" + code1.substring(20,21); } }

Comment: What is hte value of `(String) decodedStringView.getText();` ? You are not using `cardN` and `expiryDate `

Comment: thanks, the substring for String first = code.substring(1,17); works, but the second one for the date doesnt give the correct date